# Orders of Cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Suppose $\tau$ is a cycle of order $n$. I am trying to show that $\tau^k$ is a cycle if and only if $\gcd(n,k)=1$.

$\Rightarrow$ If $\gcd(n,k)=1$, then the order of $\tau^k$ is $n/\gcd(n,k)=n/1=n$. So $\tau^k$ is a cycle (I believe?)

$\Leftarrow$ Can I say that if $\tau^k$ is a cycle, it must have order $n$? I am unsure how to treat the "fixed" elements that are possible in a cycle. If one of the elements was mapped to itself, would all other elements be mapped to their respective selves as well since each element has order of $\tau$ has order $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose without loss of generality that
$$
\tau = (1, 2, \dots, n).
$$

Saying that $\tau^{k}$ is a cycle is the same as saying that $\tau^{ki}(1) \ne 1$ for $0 < i < n$. This is because the elements $\tau^{i}(1)$ will be distinct then, for $0 < i < n$: if $\tau^{i}(1) = \tau^{j}(1)$ for $0 < j < i < n$, then $\tau^{i-j}(1) = 1$, with $0 < i - j < n$.

Now if $\tau^{ki}(1) = 1$ for some $0 < i < n$, then for all $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ we have
$$
\tau^{ki}(j) = \tau^{ki}(\tau^{j-1}(1)) = \tau^{j-1}(\tau^{ki}(1))= \tau^{j-1}(1) = j,
$$
that is, $\tau^{ki}$ is the identity map.

So $\tau^{k}$ is a cycle if and only if its order is $n$. Now in a group the order of the $k$-th power of an element of period $n$ is given by
$$
\frac{n}{(n, k)}.
$$
Thus $\tau^{k}$ is a cycle if and only if $(n, k) = 1$.